# Hovering over election vote button shows irrelevant information

Tags: bug, status-completed, tooltips, election-page

On the moderator [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election), the tooltip will display the text used for voting on a question; this is incorrect.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Cast a vote for or against any candidate
2. Undo that vote

At this point, the tooltip content is changed, at least for that candidate.

See screenshots:

> [image]
>   [image]

As you can see, the message doesn't quite fit here; these are certainly not questions.

Comment: The message I get is `(click again to undo)`. What page exactly do you see this?

Comment: bug reproduced ..

Comment: After clearing cache and refreshing the page, I can still reproduce this consistently on the last candidate on the page.

Comment: Oh well. If you think that people will be confused by this tooltip that not everyone is seeing in the first place, maybe those people don't deserve to vote.

Comment: I'm not seeing this. Is your browser drunk (ie. using scripts)? [Up & down arrows](http://i.imgur.com/Wdh7JWi.png); [vote count](http://i.imgur.com/kddf9NG.png)

Comment: With the added steps to reproduce I'm indeed getting it as well.

Comment: I don't see this on chrome what browser are you using?

Comment: @user689 Safari 7.0.1 No funky settings, all extensions disabled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The primary phase election voting tooltips were overridden by the default post voting tooltips. This shouldn't be happening anymore after build rev `2014.3.4.2013` on meta and `2014.3.4.1420` on sites.

Comment: This answer shows research effort. :-)

Comment: meh, was doing some stuff around there, remembered this card..

Comment: Don't be humble on us! We know you did it to earn fame and glory. :D